# Access all event listeners in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, listener, dom-events

I want to do something like this:

```
function('string', function2(){})
```

where I leave the to user to write what he wants in the `string` parameter and than execute `function2`.
The catch is here: `string` is an event listener. When the user writes **click**, I want to call `onClick()`, when the user writes **mouse** I want to call `onMouseOver` and so on.

I have in mind doing something with `case`, but how can I access all event listeners?

Comment: for simple ones, it's just "on"+eventname;  But if you want to do anything more complex, you should create a map containing the string you want the user to use and mapping to the string you want to use, like `{'mouse': 'onmouseover', 'click': 'onclick'}`, then it's just a simple lookup

Comment: Unless you're passing arguments to the function you want to call, you should simply use `.addEventListener('eventName', function2)`, otherwise wrap `function2()` inside of an anonymous function: `.addEventListener('eventName', function(){ function2(arg1,arg2); })`. Incidentally: [`eventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener). Also, and finally, may I ask *why* you're doing this? It's an interesting approach, but I'm curious as to the problem it solves (genuinely curious, not a prelude to passive-aggressive "don't do that!")

Comment: How would this be different than the standard `addEventListener()` API?

Comment: yes, I wanna do something like that: mapping all strings to events. But how do I access ALL events? are the stored in an array of the DOM like forms?

Comment: I think I misunderstood with my comment.  Can you edit your question to make it more clear what you mean.  Perhaps a concrete example with some code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

```
element.addEventListener("string", function() {}, false);
```

However, in the case of IE <= 8, you will need to use `attachEvent` as it does not follow the standard:

```
element.attachEvent("string", function() {});
```

Finally, as kybernetikos mentions in his comment, you can then use a simple dictionary to map `mouse` to `mouseover`.

*If you wish to fire events, you should use [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).*

Comment: If I have understand it well, asker wants to fire event listeners, instead of adding them

Answer (score 0):

If you add the event listeners using the old model (i.e. `elem.onclick = function(){ /* */ };`), you can use

```
elem['on' + event]();
```

Keep in mind that this only fires the event listeners, but doesn't create an event (e.g. it won't bubble).

If you won't to create a event, which fires event listeners added using `addEventlistener`, and bubbles, and does all things a real event does, you must

1. Create your event using event constructors: `Event` or [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent)
2. Fire it with [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent)

See [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for more information and examples.

Comment: Care to explain this a little bit?

Comment: @DritjonGjimishka Are you using the new or the old model?

Comment: the old one. Basically when the user puts the string "click" I want to call the event OnClick() and execute function2() if the div is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .trigger to do this.   Check out this example in jsfiddle. type "dblclick" in the input box.

http://jsfiddle.net/jspatel/Suj4H/1/

```
<input id="writehere"> </input>
  $('#writehere').dblclick(function() {
     alert ('dblclick');
   });


$('#writehere').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        $(this).trigger( $(this).val() );
    }
});
```